# Where to place calculated property of HasChildren for Domain Model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, automapper, dto

We have an `Department` model (domain-driven design). Each department has its child departments, so domain model looks like

```
public class Department
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
  ICollection<Department> Children { get; set; }
}
```

At the API domain models of the same hierarchy path, coming from repository, it will transforms to DTO trough AutoMapper and does not include children by default.

```
public class DepartmentDto
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
  ICollection<DepartmentDto> Children { get; set; } // Empty set.
}
```

Does it a good way to add `[NotMapped] bool HasChildren` property to the `Department` domain model to show or hide expand arrows at the client? For lazy load.

This field smells strange: can be filled or can be not (depends on query).

Repository returns a collection of departments, belongs to parent Id (may become Null to root nodes):

```
ICollection<Department> GetDepartments(int? parentId = null);
```

Comment: You can remove Children from DepartmentDto and add HasChildren instead.

Comment: Property `Children` is in use by some other logic (upcoming to API).

Comment: Then in the dto, `public bool HasChildren => Children.Count > 0;`.

Comment: So we need to fetch children from database anyway? Query from repository returns collection of current hierarchy path. Each node can have it's children.

Comment: If you sometimes don't need the children, but you need to know if there are any, then you can compute HasChildren in your AM configuration. For example ChidrenCount will automatically be mapped from the source, but be sure to check the generated SQL. Check [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html).

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to use separate dto-s for each case.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) comments, I've found the solution:

IDepartmentRepository.cs

```
IQueryable<Department> GetDepartmentsQuery(int? parentId = null);
```

DepartmentsController.cs (API):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<DepartmentDto>>> GetRootDepartments()
{
    var dtoItems = await _repository.GetDepartmentsQuery()
        .ProjectTo<DepartmentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .ToListAsync();

    return Ok(dtoItems);
}
```

AutoMapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<Department, DepartmentDto>()
  .ForMember(x => x.HasChildren,
      opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.Children.Any()))
  .ForMember(x => x.Children,
      opts => opts.Ignore());
```